# Objective-C Asynchronous Methods and ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, asynchronous

I'm new to Objective-c.  I wrote a few lines of code to access a web-service asynchronously and then process the results.  Could you please explain how the ARC works when an asynchronous method takes a delegate (protocol) as an argument?

For example I'm invoking the web-service by using a local `NSURLConnection` in a method:

```
-(void) invokeSomeWebServiceMethod {
   MyDelegate *const theDelegate = ...;
   NSURL *const url = ...;
   NSURLRequest *const request = ...;
   [NSURLConnection connectionWithReuqest: request delegate:theDelegate]; 
}
```

I wasn't sure this approach would work, since the implicit `NSURLConnection` which is returned as a result of the `connectionWithRequest` message should be marked for clean-up, because neither the calling method nor the delegate has a reference to it.  But it works!

So:

1. How does the runtime know not to prematurely wipe-out the
   `NSURLConnection` that's doing work?
2. List item Should I be releasing/closing the connection in my delegate once
   `connectionDidFinishLoading` message is received?
3. Does it make more sense for the delegate to declare the `invokeSomeWebServiceMethod` and pass `self` as part of the `connectionWithRequest` message?  Then the creation of the `NSURLConnection` is encapsulated inside the delegate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. While the connection is downloading, it retains itself.
2. If you have any strong references to the connection, you should set them to nil once you're done with the connection object.
3. To answer this question, I need more information about what `MyDelegate` really is and what object currently hosts `invokeSomeWebServiceMethod`.

You can look at the retains and releases yourself by running your app under the Allocations instrument with “Record reference counts” enabled and “Only track active allocations” disabled:

[image: allocations instrument options]

Then, after running your program under Instruments, you can type “NSURLConnection” into the search bar and drill down by clicking the little white arrows in gray circles to see the trace for a single object:

[image: instruments history for one NSURLConnection]

You can see in that screen shot (right-click and open in a new tab for full size) that `-[NSURLConnectionInternal initWithInfo:]` retains the connection (line 1).  That retain is balanced by a release later after the connection has finished sending all of its delegate messages.

Comment: Thanks for this, let me play/learn the Allocation Instrument, and post back.

Comment: "While the connection is downloading, it retains itself." - Is this documented somewhere? I had a discussion about this and could not find a reference.